# Why is this zerolog hook an ineffective assignment?

Tags: go

I want to store `zerolog` messages in a slice for easy access to the last n messages. `memoryLog.messages` stays null and `golangci-lint` complains about `ineffective assignment to field memoryLog.messages`. I'm still new to Go and it feels like I'm missing something obvious, but I just can't figure it out.

```golang
type memoryLog struct {
    config   config
    messages []string
}

func (memoryLog memoryLog) Run(event *zerolog.Event, level zerolog.Level, message string) {
    memoryLog.messages = append([]string{message}, memoryLog.messages...)

    if len(memoryLog.messages) > memoryLog.config.MemoryLogMaxItems {
        memoryLog.messages = memoryLog.messages[:memoryLog.config.MemoryLogMaxItems]
    }
}
```

```golang
memoryLog := memoryLog{config: config}
logger := log.Hook(memoryLog)
```

Comment: You missed the difference between pointers and non-pointers. Your Run method operators on a copy of the struct, because you have defined it as a method on the struct, not as a method on a pointer to the struct. See, for example, https://medium.com/@meeusdylan/when-to-use-pointers-in-go-44c15fe04eac

Comment: The copy of messages you modify _is_ effective.

Comment: Thanks, so this not possible since I have to implement `zerolog.Hook`?

Comment: I don't see how that is a problem. Just change `func (memoryLog memoryLog)` to `func (memoryLog *memoryLog)` (although I suggest not shadowing the type name `memoryLog` with the name of the receiver variable: give the receiver a different name)

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I tried it and get this error: `memoryLog does not implement zerolog.Hook (Run method has pointer receiver)`.

Comment: Change the line to: `logger := log.Hook(&memoryLog)`, or just `var logger log.Hook = &memoryLog`. (and again, don't shadow a type name with a local variable name - that gets really confusing and you'll be unable to create a new memoryLog struct in the lines where the local variable name is in scope)

Comment: Ah, I see, that makes sense... Thanks again. Yes, I renamed it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the help I got it working:

```golang
func (log *memoryLog) Run(event *zerolog.Event, level zerolog.Level, message string) {
    //...
}
```

```golang
logger := log.Hook(&memoryLog)
```